Why can't I inline this powershell script?
The following works:
$rule = new-object security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule "LOCAL SERVICE", "read", allow
$path = "$($ENV:ALLUSERSPROFILE)\Microsoft\Crypto\Keys\$(([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.RSACertificateExtensions]::GetRSAPrivateKey($selfCert)).key.UniqueName)"
$permissions = Get-Acl -Path $path
$permissions.AddAccessRule($rule)
Set-Acl -Path $path -AclObject $permissions

The following does not:
$rule = new-object security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule "LOCAL SERVICE", "read", allow
$path = "$($ENV:ALLUSERSPROFILE)\Microsoft\Crypto\Keys\$(([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.RSACertificateExtensions]::GetRSAPrivateKey($selfCert)).key.UniqueName)"
Set-Acl -Path $path -AclObject (Get-Acl -Path $path).AddAccessRule($rule)

Set-Acl : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'AclObject' because it is null. At C:\Users\me\Downloads\Self Signed Cert.ps1:64 char:32
+ ... Acl -Path $path -AclObject (Get-Acl -Path $path).AddAccessRule($rule)
+                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-Acl], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAclCommand

Why can't I inline the code as shown?

The return type of the AddAccessRule method if void, meaning it doesn't return anything. You'll have to write at least 2 separate statements

you'd need to do some nasty stuff to make it a one-liner like Set-Acl -Path $path -AclObject (($acl = Get-Acl $pwd).AddAccessRule($rule) && $acl) in pwsh 7 or Set-Acl -Path $path -AclObject $(($acl = Get-Acl $pwd).AddAccessRule($rule); $acl) in pwsh 5.1

@SantiagoSquarzon I see that and it makes sense. Was hoping to avoid that. But at least it answers the question. If you want to submit the answer I'll mark it as such. Thanks.

The key pointer was provided by Mathias in a comment, the second example fails because AddAccessRule doesn't have a return value, it's a void method. You'd need to do it in separated statements as in your first example.
If you wanted to do it as a one-liner, which personally, wouldn't recommend as it becomes less readable can be in PowerShell 7+:
Set-Acl -Path $path -AclObject (($acl = Get-Acl $path).AddAccessRule($rule) && $acl)

And, in PowerShell 5.1, since there is no chaining operator (&&), you can use $(..) with ; as a statement delimiter:
Set-Acl -Path $path -AclObject $(($acl = Get-Acl $path).AddAccessRule($rule); $acl)

In both cases you can note the use of:
($acl = Get-Acl $path)

This means that there is an assignment and also an output of that assignment, this is known as variable squeezing in some languages or Grouping assignment statements in PowerShell.
